# Previewing an html document using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

Trying to learn jquery. Came across this code about previewing textarea input through an iframe.

**HTML**

```
<div class="content">
  <textarea></textarea>
  <iframe></iframe>
</div>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(function () {
  'use strict';
  $(document).ready( function () {
    $('div.content textarea').keyup( function () {
      $('iframe').attr('srcdoc', $(this).val());
    });
  });
});
```

I thought html elements would require using **.html()** rather than **.attr()** to preview the textarea input and html markup? Don't get me wrong, it works, just don't understand why not just use .html() method. What's the difference between both methods?

Comment: THANK YOU!!! I had been trying to figure out how to get JQuery, CSS, and HTML to work together from a textarea into an iframe and your code example here worked like a charm. So, THANK YOU very much, Alloc. Wayne

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**.html()** returns what's inside of an html tag. So if you call it on a div tag it will return whatever is between `<div></div>`. The **.attr** function returns the value of an attribute, such as the `src` attribute on a `img`, the `href` attribute on an anchor. The `srcdoc` attribute of iframe is a weird one since this attribute accepts html. What you are doing in your example is the equivalent of the following in plain JS:

```
document.getElementById("exampleFrame").srcdoc = "<div>html inside iframe</div>";
```

There is technically nothing inside of `<iframe></iframe>`, but rather in the srcdoc attribute of `<iframe srcdoc="some html"></iframe>`. Hence why you need to call **.attr**.

More info: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#Attributes)

Answer (score 1):

An iframe has it's own window which is isolated from the parent page window and is not a standard content element.

It has it's own document , body etc as well.

To set `html()` in it you have to first get inside that window to work with it's internal document.

The srcdoc is simply a shortcut path to setting content in the iframe document